# Moving context definition to separate file from provider breaking tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have a `React.createContext` and the `context.provider` instance that I am using with my code and initially had them in the same file as it is always shown within demonstrations and the official docs.

I however, have decided to move the `React.createContext()` into a different file alongside other exported functions that make use of it.

Since doing this, I have noticed that my tests are breaking around an area that has nothing to do with the files being tests/used...

I'm just wondering if there was an obvious reason why my context wouldn't work properly after I'd put them into separate files?

MyContext/index.js

```
export const MyContext = React.createContext({});
```

MyContext/MyProvider.js

```
return <MyContext.Provider value={{data: 'some-data'}}>
    {children}
</MyContext.Provider>
```

MyContext/MyProvider.test.js

```
it('Should render child of provider', () => {
    let component;

    act(() => {
        component = renderer.create(
            <MyProvider>test test</MyProvider>
        );
    });

    expect(component.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the main issue was that my context was within the main `index.js` file that is exported...

Moving this code to another file helped everything work.